# What does "expect little out of discussion" means?

Tags: phrase-meaning

It was a part of a news:

> The talks went for hours, and while they brought some hope for an end to the war, Ukraine's president and residents in Kyiv made it clear they **expected little** out of the discussion.

What does the last part mean? Does it mean that they didn't expect that the discussion would be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally, to "expect little" out of something means to expect that the "something" is unlikely to produce something good or meaningful, but the nuanced meaning is closer to, "I expect *nothing* good or meaningful."

So, let's say I have just applied for a job that I don't think I'll get. If I say...

> I **have low expectations** from this process.

... it means I'm not really expecting to get the job, but I'm optimistic that I might.

But if I say...

> I **expect little** to come out of this process.

... it means something like, I think it's a waste of time, and I'll be shocked if I get the job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; the understood meaning is "they expected little **[progress to come]** out of **[or 'be produced by']** the discussion.